# Unable to import module in AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script named `foo.py`. It has a lambda handler function defined like this:

```
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        download_path = '/tmp/{}.gz'.format(key)
        csv_path = '/tmp/{}.csv'.format(key)
        ... proceed to proprietary stuff
```

This is in a zip file like so:

```
-foo.zip
    -foo.py
    -dependencies
```

I have uploaded this zip file to AWS Lambda and configured an AWS Lambda Function to run `foo.handler`. However, every time I test it, I get `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'foo'"`.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

`stat --format '%a' foo.py` shows `664`

Comment: Where are you importing foo.py?  I don't understand why you want to import your "main" Lambda module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I was importing `psycopg2` in my lambda function, which requires `libpq.so`, which installs with Postgres. Postgres isn't installed in the lambda environment, so importing `psycopg2` failed, which meant that, by extension, Amazon's import of my lambda function also failed. Not a very helpful error message, though.

Thankfully, somebody's built a version of `psycopg2` that works with AWS lambda: https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2